How to know if React Native app is manually opened by the user?
The problem statement is - I want to track exclusively that the app is either opened manually by the user, or by a push notification or a deeplink click.
The Push notif and deeplink opens can be easily bifurcated as both have diff listeners and I can put a tracker there and both will be fired exclusively (never overlapping).
But the problem is - the app open code runs all the time even when the app is manually open or in the cases of push or deeplink click.
How do i exclusively track only the natural app opens by user? Is there a way to do so.
Thanks

You can also use tools like MoEngage for user activity analysis. where you can add custom events like "clicked notification", "clicked in app message", "Home viewed" etc with custom attributes whatever you want.
